# Postgres Index to speed up LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, indexing, left-join, query-optimization

Within my db I have table prediction_fsd with about 5 million entries. The site table contains approx 3 million entries. I need to execute queries that look like

```
SELECT prediction_fsd.id AS prediction_fsd_id, 
       prediction_fsd.site_id AS prediction_fsd_site_id, 
       prediction_fsd.html_hash AS prediction_fsd_html_hash, 
       prediction_fsd.prediction AS prediction_fsd_prediction, 
       prediction_fsd.algorithm AS prediction_fsd_algorithm, 
       prediction_fsd.model_version AS prediction_fsd_model_version,
       prediction_fsd.timestamp AS prediction_fsd_timestamp, 
       site_1.id AS site_1_id, 
       site_1.url AS site_1_url, 
       site_1.status AS site_1_status 
  FROM prediction_fsd
  LEFT OUTER JOIN site AS site_1
         ON site_1.id = prediction_fsd.site_id 
 WHERE 95806 = prediction_fsd.site_id
   AND prediction_fsd.algorithm = 'xgboost'
 ORDER BY prediction_fsd.timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

at the moment this query takes about ~4 seconds. I'd like to reduce that by introducing an index. Which tables and fields should I include in that index. I'm having troubles properly understanding the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of Postgres

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the query plan in plain text? It's now impossible to read and analyse

Comment: And it looks like you got no (combined) index on site_id and algorithm. timestamp could be part of that index as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX prediction_fsd_site_id_algorithm_timestamp
    ON public.prediction_fsd USING btree
    (site_id, algorithm, "timestamp" DESC)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

By introducing a combined index as suggested by Frank Heikens I was able to bring down the query execution time to 0.25s

Answer (score 0):

These three SQL lines point to a possible BTREE index to help you.

```sql
WHERE 95806 = prediction_fsd.site_id
   AND prediction_fsd.algorithm = 'xgboost'
 ORDER BY prediction_fsd.timestamp DESC
```

You're filtering the rows of the table by equality on two columns, and ordering by the third column.  So try this index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX site_alg_ts ON prediction_fsd 
      (site_id, algorithm, timestamp DESC);
```

This BTREE index lets PostgreSQL random-access it to the first eligible row, which happens also to be the row you want with your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` clause.

The query plan in your question says that PostgreSQL did an expensive Parallel Sequential Scan on all five megarows of that table. This index will almost certainly change that to a cheap index lookup.

On the other table, it appears that you already look up rows in it via the primary key `id`. So you don't need any other index for that one.